# issue in removing a specific character in a string

Tags: python-3.x

i keep getting TypeError: can only join an iterable.
I am trying to remove a specific character from a string in python.

```
def get_2s_and_5s_removed(dice_string):   
    dice_string =list(dice_string)
    if '2' in dice_string:
      dice_string =dice_string.remove('2')
      return ''.join(dice_string)
    if '5' in dice_string:
      dice_string =dice_string.remove('5')
      return ''.join(dice_string)**
```

Comment: Do you want to remove *all* 2s and 5s as the name implies?  Your algorithm, if it worked, would remove one 2 else one 5.

Comment: then should i add a while loop and a broke statement  to it

Answer (score 3):

Python's `remove` method modifies the list itself and doesn't return a new list containing the original list minus the removed values. The correct way to use it would be: `dice_string.remove('2')` (i.e. don't use an equal sign with it, as it will assign `NoneType` to the variable).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to remove *all* 2s and 5s as the function name implies, all you really need is `.replace`:

```
>>> '11223245565'.replace('2','').replace('5','')
'11346'
```